# How to initialize LinearLayout variable?

Tags: android

*Quick notice: I am using `SharedPreferences` so that I can reload data when I re-open the app.*

**Problem**
I have a `LinearLayout` in the main fragment of my application. Everything runs smoothly until I re-open the app and try to reinitialize the `LinearLayout`.

I am trying to initialize the `LinearLayout` with `findViewById()`. I have put the function in many different places. Currently I am trying to get it to work in `onCreate` and a function that is called from `onCreate`. Here is my code so far:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        // this is where is load the SharedPreferences

        // this is where I implement them back into the app ('reload' the app)
        reload();
    }

    public void reload() {

        // bunch of other irrelevant stuff

        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        linearLayout.addView(/*other view*/); // this is where it complains
    }

    // the is for when the button is clicked
    public void submitEntry(View view) {

        // this is fine according to Logcat
        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    }
}
```

I would expect after initializing it twice, or at least trying to, that is would've caught on but no. Logcat complains that linearLayout is a `null object reference`. I don't know what to do at this point but it's probably something simple that I've overlooked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the `LinearLayout` is in a `Fragment`, you should be finding and populating it in the `Fragment`, not the `Activity`.

Comment: You are initializing it again and again. why?

Comment: if you want reinit linearlayout then you just pass null before reinit

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani because I want to make this work and nothing is working.

Comment: @AnasMehar could you explain a little more? Like how I would do that?

Comment: You should define **linearLayout** in your fragment view because there you are using it. There is no make sense to define in activity.

Comment: In your reload method you try to reinit linearlayout to before findviewbyid just put linearlayout  = null

Comment: `in the main fragment of my application` you didn't show the code of that fragment. ALso if the layout is in Fragment, then why are you trying to manipulate it in activity?

Answer (score 0):

**LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(context);**
Initialize like this it will help you!

Comment: Thank you for answering but I'm trying to get a hold of a `LinearLayout` that is already in the application.